# Django ModelChoiceField queryset does not return actual values from db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

My models are:

```
class ActionType(models.Model):


    id_action_type = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'action_type'

class TicketsForm(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    ticket_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True, null=True)
```

In my forms i have:

```
class BankForm(forms.ModelForm):

    action_type= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ActionType.objects.all(),widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = TicketsForm
        fields = ('ticket_type',
                  'action_type',)
```

When this is rendered to html i Don't see the actual values of `ActionType.objects.all()` but instead i see
`ActionType object` 
`ActionType object` near RadioButton.
Can anyone tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: Can the down-voter please comment and mention the reason

Comment: You are returning a reference. For avoid it you must to define __str__, which set what you are returning when you are calling an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `__str__` method for your model. For example:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ActionType(models.Model):
    id_action_type = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    ...

    def __str__(self)
        return self.action_name
```

The `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator is only required if you are using Python 2. See the [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str) docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because you have no `__str__(self)` or `__unicode__(self)` method defined on your ActionType model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str for details.

I would however strongly recommend to use a ForeignKey in `TicketsForm` to `ActionType`. Also, I'm not sure what necessitates defining your own private keys; if you don't define these, Django will generate them for you. See the tutorial for more details (esp. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/ on models).